# How to identify if each random number is hit error

Tags: c, arrays, random, multidimensional-array

so I was writing a program where I need to generate a set of random numbers from 1 to a certain number that the user enters.  Then identify the approximate probability that each number from 1 to N was hit, by the random numbers generated. So for my code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
printf("Enter a number");
int input;
scanf("%d",&input);
getRandomIntFrom0ToK(input);
return 0;
}

void getRandomIntFrom0ToK (int K)
{
int i;
int j;
int a[2][K+1];
int b[999][999]; 
int counter=0;

srand(time(NULL));

for (i=0;i<K;i++) //Here I am storing the random numbers and indexes of each number 
{
   a[0][i] = i;
   a[1][i]=rand()%K;

}

for(i=0;i<K;i++)//In another array transferring the indexes from the first array
{
    b[0][i]=a[0][i];
}
for(i=0;i<K;i++)//Setting the second column of array b to 0
{
    b[1][i]=0;

}


for(i=0;i<K;i++)//Running two for loops to check in array a if any of the values from the index are equal to any of the random numbers in the second column
{
    for(j=0;j<K;j++)
    {

        if(a[0][i]==a[1][j])//If they are then make the index of array b corresponding to the number equal to 0+1, I will eventually add a certain probability but for now I just want to see that it works
        {
            b[1][i]=b[1][i]+1;

        }
    }
}//Up till here if I run the program, it works

/*for(i=0;i<K;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",b[0][i]);
}*/

}
```

So the problem is that when include a printf statement for the b array, the program does not work.  I know that my code is very inefficient, but I just want to know what I am doing wrong.  Eventually what I want to do is print out both columns of the b array so that it outputs the number and corresponding percentage which i will do using (1/K*100) on to the screen.  Thanks, any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: start by making `main()` return `int` and indenting your code.

Comment: Then continue with showing us `Console-Output` and `Error-Output` if exists.

Comment: I made main return an int and for the error-output (Process returned 255 <0xFF>)

Comment: Also the problem only persists when I try to print the value of the b array

Comment: Edit your question.Add your input,expected output and actual output you are getting.

Comment: It's gonna "work" (somehow) if you decrease the size of table b.

Comment: Why have you hard coded array `b` (the first dimension) to have `999` elements when you only use the first two?

Answer (score 0):

2 problems: Missing prototype & excessive use of stack space.

OP calls `getRandomIntFrom0ToK(input);` without declaring it first.  Not likely a major issue.  This problem is telling as it causes a typical warning.  Thus implying the compiler warnings are ignored or not fully enabled.

```
void getRandomIntFrom0ToK (int K);
int main(void) {
  ...
  getRandomIntFrom0ToK(input);
  return 0;
}
```

OP creates a *large* variable, likely an issue.  Curious, as much smaller one would suffice for OP's post.  The compiler, without the `printf("%d\n",b[0][i])`, may optimize this variable out as its values are never read, only assigned.  As this variable is millions of bytes long, its presence (or not) may have significant result on code operation for stack space is often more limited that space via `malloc()`.

```
void getRandomIntFrom0ToK (int K) {
  ...
  // b is maybe millions of bytes
  // int b[999][999]; 
  // Code only uses b[0][...] and b[1][...] 
  int b[2][999];
```

If `b[999][999]` is truly needed, suggest using `malloc()` to provide the space.